# Equal functions almos everywhere Riemann integrable

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I am looking for an example of two functions which are the same function almost everywhere (they are equal everywhere except from a null set), but one of them is Riemann integrable and the other one it is not.

Comment: What examples do you know of non-Riemann integrable functions? Something with rationals and irrationals involved is likely the case. Try to use that function as a hint for this problem.

Comment: Yes, I can think of the Dirichlet function which is non-Riemann integrable and the function f(x)=1, for all x in [0,1], which is Riemann integrable.

Comment: @user832184: you should rather take $f(x)=0$ ;-)

Comment: OK, thank you :)

Comment: That's your counterexample, sealed and stamped. Please write an answer and mark it correct yourself. Otherwise, you can delete the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Dirichlet function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_function#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20Dirichlet%20function,mathematician%20Peter%20Gustav%20Lejeune%20Dirichlet.) which is non-Riemann integrable and the function $f(x)=0$, for all $x \in [0,1]$, which is Riemann integrable.

Comment: Excellent, +1. You can write a line or two, or provide a link as to why the Dirichlet function is non-Riemann integrable and why the two functions are a.e. equal, since you won't be the only one reading your answer, there are others on the site too. But otherwise, we are good. If there are no better answers, kindly accept your answer after some time. Thanks. I will edit your post to show how mathematics is written on the site as well.